# How to make bootstrap 4 table maintain th width throughout rows?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with an issue regarding a bootstrap table. Please, see if you can help me out. I have the following structure:

Full code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> ID</th>
                <th class="text-left col-3"> Name</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Field1</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Field2</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Date X</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Current situation</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Is company</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Phone</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Net worth</th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="d-flex">
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <p>string-filter</p>
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <p>date-filter</p>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p>select-filter</p>
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>1</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-3">
                    <label>Bollumba Bar</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>055.485-65799</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>05/11/2017 3:22</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>Active</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>No</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>(271) 998-4512</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>$ 1,548,655.00</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>2</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-3">
                    <label>My big name for that specific company</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>22.585/754/000188</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>12/05/2018 10:19</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>Inactive</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>Yes</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>(277) 315-4848</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>$ 20,152,657.00</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>3</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-3">
                    <label>Pluribus unum</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>255.576/47/488</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>05/11/2017 3:24</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>Active</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>No</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>(279) 887-4513</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>$ 2,548,655.00</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Bootply version: https://www.bootply.com/BWfGUAjKKz

I'd like for each column to maintain the same width as the parent `th` (the first `tr` inside `thead`). Those sizes are dynamic, the user can choose to set the size of one, a few, all or no columns, hence my usage of `col-md-auto` for the "other" columns. The problem is, the first row (`th`) assumes the right behavior, but the other ones don't.

Basically, if the first `th` has a width of 75px, all the other cells in that column would also have that width, regardless of their content. Which is the "default" table behavior. But since I need to customize the widths of some columns I'm kinda lost here. My CSS skills are pretty basic.

By the way, I'm using `d-flex` so the header text won't break.

How can I fix this behavior?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The d-flex is causing your issues. If you want to prevent word wrapping just use `white-space: nowrap;` on your th elements.

```css
th{
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> ID</th>
                <th class="text-left col-3"> Name</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Field1</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Field2</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Date X</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Current situation</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Is company</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Phone</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-auto"> Net worth</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <p>string-filter</p>
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <p>date-filter</p>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p>select-filter</p>
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>1</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-3">
                    <label>Bollumba Bar</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>055.485-65799</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>05/11/2017 3:22</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>Active</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>No</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>(271) 998-4512</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>$ 1,548,655.00</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>2</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-3">
                    <label>My big name for that specific company</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>22.585/754/000188</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>12/05/2018 10:19</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>Inactive</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>Yes</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>(277) 315-4848</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>$ 20,152,657.00</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>3</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-3">
                    <label>Pluribus unum</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>255.576/47/488</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>05/11/2017 3:24</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>Active</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>No</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>(279) 887-4513</label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left col-md-auto">
                    <label>$ 2,548,655.00</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try it right away. Does it still make sense to use `col-md-auto` if I'm not using `d-flex`? Does it still work properly?

Comment: it's not working :/ by removing `d-flex` I can't set the size of the columns anymore. For example, using my example code `col-3` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: col are meant to be used inside of rows.  That is part of the grid layout.  When you add d-flex to a table, it will not align the columns correctly.  If you want to specifically resize a single column, you can do it with width.  The other columns will always be auto.

Comment: so you're saying I shouldn't use col inside a table? If so, how would I adjust the columns' widths then?

Comment: You can set the width and min-width css properties to adjust the width.

Comment: what about without using pixels? I'd like to leverage the usage of `col`